How should the drain on this sink supposed to operate?
I have an old sink exactly like this one. The drain is clogged and unfortunately I can't do anything to fix it because the plug is frozen in place with corrosion/gunk.  Is the lever behind the spigot supposed to turn to operate it? It is also stuck but if I knew which way it was supposed to move that might help.
I do not want to use any chemicals (Drano, etc.).

Here is what I see underneath.  There is not an obvious linkage to connect the lever to the plug that I can see.

EDIT: the drain plug is stuck open; the lever is all the way to the right, if that matters.

Are the pipes clogged or just the stopper?  Pouring some vinegar over the stopper might loosen it a bit.  I would guess the lever turns to the left to open/raise the stopper, but just as likely it turns down.

Can try wedging something under the stopper to try to help with lifting, but do not use much force.  The sink will not like that, finger/thumb force should be plenty.

@isherwood added picture of underside

Is it a spring-loaded popup drain?  I had one that needed to be cycled periodically or deposits would make it not operate smoothly and it'd get stuck, requiring drain disassembly.
